# Android HTTP Headers with API

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

What are headers used for if I want to do a post request & response ?
How is it possible to "save" token there ?

I can't find any good explanation about it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Retrofit to call api and store token into shared preferences and add common headers to OkhttpClient

```
        val prefs = Prefs.getInstance();

        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        httpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            val request = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", prefs.token)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .method(original.method, original.body)
                .build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor)

        val client = httpClient.build()
```

and make Retrofit object like this

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(
                GsonConverterFactory.create(
                    GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                )
            )
            .client(client).build()
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that token is suppose to be saved at shared preferences. 
I see that header "Authorization" is added and token is extracted from shared preferences. But what why interceptor? What if I got 1 access token and 1 refresh token? Bit confusing

Comment: Interceptors are used for Logging purpose or Rewriting Requests/Responses.
checkout: https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/

and for token and refresh token you can add as many headers as you needed backend will fetch only necessary headers.

Comment: Is this a way to add a new header with refreshtoken for example?
.header("Authorization", prefs.token + prefs.refreshtoken)

Comment: No, it is builder pattern you need to do like .header("Authorization", prefs.token).header("HEADER_NAME", prefs. refreshtoken)